# Required ModelValidation just for new objects ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate, model-validation

I have this issue since yesterday.
In my User model I have a **[NotMapped]** called "**ConfirmPassword**". I don´t save it on the database but I use it on my Create form as a always to validate the data input for new users.

Since than, it´s ok. The problem is on my [HttpPost] Edit action. I should be able to edit some user's data without type and confirm the password. I use both Password and ConfirmPassword as a way to confirm the old password and informe the new one, if I wanna change the password. But, if I don´t, I leave them blank.

I have used already the code below to be able to pass the ModelState.IsValid() condition and it worked:

```
ModelState["Password"].Errors.Clear();
ModelState["ConfirmPassword"].Errors.Clear();
```

But, just before the db.SaveChanges(), as User user view model is considered, it has both properties empty and I got:

```
Property: ConfirmPassword Error: The field ConfirmPassword is invalid.
```

The question is: How could I skip de Required model validation when I want to update an object?

I read already about custom ModelValidations with classes extending **ValidationAttribute** and
**DataAnnotationsModelValidator** but I am not doing it right.

Any idea? How could I create a custom model validation that checks if the UserId property is null or not. It´s a nice way to check if I'm in Create or Edit action.

Thanks,
Paulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the domain objects as your ViewModel will leads you to a condition of  less scalability. I would opt for seperate ViewModels specific for the Views. When i have to save the data i map the ViewModel to the Domain model and save that. In your speciific case, i would create 2 ViewModels

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
  public string FirstName { set;get;}
  public string LastName { set;get;}
}
```

And i will Have another `ViewModel` which **inherits** from the above class, for the `Create` View

```
public class CustomerCreateViewModel :CustomerViewModel
{
   [Required]
   public string Password { set;get;}

   [Required]
   public string ConfirmPassword { set;get;}
}
```

Now in my Get actions, i use this ViewModel

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm=new CustomerCreateViewModel();
  return View(vm);
}
```

and of course my View(`create.cshtml`) is now binded to this ViewModel

```
@model CustomerCreateViewModel
<h2>Create Csustomer</h2/>
//Other form stuff
```

Similarly for My `Edit` Action,

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  var vm=new CustomerViewModel();
  var domainCustomer=repo.GetCustomerFromID(id);
  if(domainCustomer!=null)
  {
      //This manual mapping can be replaced by AutoMapper.
      vm.FirstName=domainCustomer.FirstName;
      vm.LastName=domainCustomer.LastName;
  }
  return View(vm);
}
```

This view is bounded to CustomerViewModel

```
@model CustomerViewModel
<h2>Edit Info of @Model.FirstName</h2>
//Other form stuff
```

In your `POST` Actions, Map it back to the Domain object and Save

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CustomerCreateViewModel model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
      var domainCust=new Customer();
      domainCust.FirstName=model.FirstName;
      repo.InsertCustomer(domainCust);
      //Redirect if success (to follow PRG pattern)
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Instead of writing the Mapping yourself, you may consider using AutoMapper library to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, Shyju! I think this can save me :) My User classes already inherits from MembershipUser but I can create a new one that inherits from User. Thanks

Comment: But Shyju, using this solutions I must have a Edit view for each class, right?

Comment: you mean the ViewModel ? If you want seperate Validations for Create and Edit, You should have seperate ViewModels. But you can make use of Inheritance to keep it DRY